# pandas change column value based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, multiple-columns

I am trying to change [age] values with random number in the range defined in [tranches_age] column

| index | age | tranches_age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | 80-85 |
| 2 | NaN | 70-75 |
| 3 | NaN | 30-35 |

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, None, '80-85'], 
    [2, None, '70-75'], 
    [3, None, '30-35']], 
    columns=['index', 'age', 'tranches_age']
)


def transform(x):
    agemin, agemax = map(int, x.split('-'))
    return random.randint(agemin, agemax)

df['age'] = df['tranches_age'].apply(transform)
```

Should output things like

```
   index  age tranches_age
0      1   85        80-85
1      2   71        70-75
2      3   35        30-35
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Compute `min` and `width` of the range and then generate random number using `(min + width*np.random.random())`.
We can vectorize these operations and hence probably better performance.

Use:

```
min_r = df.tranches_age.str[:2].astype(int)
widths = df.tranches_age.str[3:].astype(int) - min_r
df['age'] = (min_r + widths* np.random.random(size=(widths.shape[0]))).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   index  age tranches_age
0      1   82        80-85
1      2   70        70-75
2      3   31        30-35
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `numpy` `random.randint`

```
df['new'] = df['tranches_age'].apply(lambda x : np.random.randint(low=x.split('-')[0],high=x.split('-')[1]))
0    83
1    72
2    32
Name: tranches_age, dtype: int64
```